# HTTPS iframe inside an HTTPS page

Tags: security-certificate

I'm developing a Wifi Homepage, which comes by default for all the users of the hotspot. In order to redirect them properly to my homepage, I'm using an SSL certificate, and the page is hosted locally.

Now I need to embed in that page an external page, which is also HTTPS.

Would that create any issue for the users (25k a day)?

Comment: Depends on your server resources. HTTPs is not that expensive.  Where you will have issues is when someone loads non SSL content into the frame.  You will get Mixed content warnings in the browser that some of this content is not secure.  It may scare off your visitors. 

I think if you frame in an SSL page in an HTML page then these warnings do not exist.   Thats how banks used to do it a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

In case of SSL pages, as long both pages certificates are properly installed and valid. In case one of those is not working, you will face some certificate alerts on your browser. So make sure both pages work individually on HTTPS before using iframes.

The biggest proof that an HTTPS iframe is not a problem inside an HTTPS page is any Facebook App. Any app in Facebook.com is actually an iframe pointing somewhere else with a valid SSL Certificate.